# Why can't this recur function be defined?

Tags: clojure

This works fine:

```
(defn fact [x]
  (loop [n x prod 1]
    (if (= 1 n)
      prod
      (recur (dec n) (* prod n)))))
```

and this one can even be evaluated as a symbol:

```
(defn fact2 []
  (loop [prod [1 2 3]]
    (if (empty? prod)
      prod
      (recur (rest prod) (* prod 2)))))
```

What's wrong with the second one?

Comment: Your second loop lacks the second argument. The first example accepts `n` and `prod` and the second one just `prod` - but the second `recur` still passes two arguments.

Comment: For future reference: "does not work" is a bad problem statement.
Please also add the error you see.

Comment: Good point on the "does not work"... I'll do better in the future. I actually couldn't find the error message this time due to my likely badly set up tools... but I could have created an new environment and should have.

Comment: Thank you... both you and erdos got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the exception thrown on evaluating the second expression:

```
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at user/fact2 (test.clj:3).
Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 1 args, got: 2
```

The `loop` binding in `fact2` has only one variable (which is called `prod`), however, the `recur` call would pass 2 values. You can not use the single variable `prod` to hold both the product (a number) and the list of numbers (a collection).

The correct definition would look something like this:

```
(defn fact2 []
  (loop [n [1 2 3] prod 1]
    (if (empty? n)
      prod
      (recur (rest n) (* prod 2)))))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was noticing that all the examples of recur online often resembled your correct answer but couldn't figure out why.